# generating random values based on condition in structured array python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array representing a position (x,y) and colors (r,g,b). Right now the array turns all zeros (as it should). I need to make it so that the values of x and y are random and <=10. I need to make the values of r,g, and b to also be random but <=255. How do you specify to only generate to 10 for 'position' and likewise to 255 for 'color'.

```
array = np.zeros(10, [ ('position', [ ('x', float, 1),
                                   ('y', float, 1)]),
                    ('color',    [ ('r', float, 1),
                                   ('g', float, 1),
                                   ('b', float, 1)])])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.random.randint`.  As an example, to generate a 2x5 array of integers from 1 to 10, use:

```
In [8]: np.random.randint(1, 10, (2,5))
Out[8]: 
array([[7, 7, 5, 6, 3],
       [6, 3, 6, 8, 3]])
```

Similarly, to generate a 2x5 shaped array of floating point numbers from 0 to 10:

```
In [10]: 10*np.random.random((2,5))
Out[10]: 
array([[  9.50898995e+00,   5.67913201e+00,   7.77076899e+00,
          3.77030483e+00,   9.67766293e-01],
       [  9.93215775e+00,   6.40290706e+00,   9.70962150e+00,
          5.98875979e-03,   5.65110883e+00]])
```

Documentation on `np.random.randint` is available [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) and documentation for `np.random.random` is [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html#numpy.random.random).

#### Python2

Using the above functions, we can generate floating point numbers of the shape you desire:

```
np.array(
    zip(10*np.random.random((10,2)),
    255*np.random.random((10,3))),
    [ ('position', [ 
         ('x', float, 1),
         ('y', float, 1)]),
         ('color',    [
               ('r', float, 1),
               ('g', float, 1),
               ('b', float, 1)])
         ]
)
```

#### Python3

With one minor change, the above works under Py3:

```
np.array(
    list(zip(10*np.random.random((10,2)),
    255*np.random.random((10,3)))),
    [ ('position', [ 
         ('x', float, 1),
         ('y', float, 1)]),
         ('color',    [
               ('r', float, 1),
               ('g', float, 1),
               ('b', float, 1)])
         ]
     )
```

Comment: it doesn't matter if they are integers or not. I am trying to see how within this array I can generate random numbers up to 10 for all values within position and random numbers up to 255 for all values within color.

Comment: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'zip'

Comment: @mmb_rach It ran fine for me.  I just copied-and-pasted from the answer and it still runs fine for me.

Comment: must be different python versions, thanks for help though

Comment: @mmb_rach Are you on Python3?  That does require a small change: answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import random 
import numpy

array = numpy.zeros(10, [ ('position', [ ('x', float, 1),
                                   ('y', float, 1)]),
                    ('color',    [ ('r', float, 1),
                                   ('g', float, 1),
                                   ('b', float, 1)])])


ranPos = lambda: random.random() * 10
ranColor = lambda: random.random() * 255

for i in range(10):
    array[i] = ((ranPos(), ranPos()),
                (ranColor(), ranColor(), ranColor()))
```

If you want to generate integers use this instead:

```
ranPos = lambda: random.randint(0,10)
ranColor = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
```